# How to test async code with Jest without passing it as a callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, jestjs, inquirer

Will be grateful if someone could clarify to me how test the async code from **inquirer** plugin for CLI app.

The module exports `updateView` function, which calls async `inquirer.prompt` inside.

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");

const getAnswer = async (request) => {
    const answer = await inquirer.prompt(request);
    return answer;
}
```

Want to test with **Jest** that async code works, however all the **Jest** examples I have seen show ways to test async code only if I pass async function as a parameter.

So my function will have to be refactored to that:

*getAnswers.js*

```
const getAnswer = async (request, callback) => {
    const answer = await callback(request);
    return answer;
}
```

*main.js*

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const getAnswers = require("./getAnswers");

const main = async () => {
    const request = "abc";
    const result = await getAnswers(request, inquirer.prompt);
...
}
```

And then test file will look like that:

*test.js*

```
const getAnswers = require("./getAnswers");

  test("async code works", async () => {
    //Arrange
    const mock = async () => {
      return "Correct Answer";
    };

    //Act
    const result = await getAnswers("abc", mock);

    //Assert
    expect(result).toEqual("Correct Answer";);
  });
```

Will be very grateful if someone could suggest if there is a way of testing async function without passing it as a callback?

And if the approach itself is correct.

Comment: Did you mean `await getAnswers(…)` instead of `async getAnswers(…)`?

Comment: Yes, definitely,  thank you, will correct the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jest.mock` to mock the imported dependencies rather than pass them as parameters. Here is the unit test solution:

`getAnswers.js`:

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const getAnswers = async (request) => {
  const answer = await inquirer.prompt(request);
  return answer;
};

module.exports = getAnswers;
```

`getAnswers.test.js`:

```js
const getAnswers = require('./getAnswers');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

jest.mock('inquirer', () => {
  return { prompt: jest.fn() };
});

describe('59495121', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    inquirer.prompt.mockResolvedValueOnce('Correct Answer');
    const actual = await getAnswers('abc');
    expect(actual).toBe('Correct Answer');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59495121/getAnswers.test.js (10.172s)
  59495121
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 getAnswers.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.367s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59495121

Comment: Thank you very much, you answer helped a lot!